# Why is the string comparison not yielding a result?

Tags: jquery, string, comparison

I'm trying to compare the value of a text input with a string between `<h>` tags using ids, but nothing's happening.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  var a = $("#name").val();
  var b = $("#verifyname").innerHTML;
  if (string(a).upper() == b.upper()) {
    $("#one").innerHTML = "right";
  } else {
    $("#one").innerHTML = "wrong";
  }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

jQuery doesn't have an `innerHTML` property. I would assume you want to use [`.html()`](https://api.jquery.com/html) or [`.text()`](https://api.jquery.com/text) instead. Also, JS has no `string()` or `upper()` methods. The latter would be `toUpperCase()`.

With those corrections made, the code would look something like this:

```js
jQuery($ => {
  checkName(); // check on load
  $('button').on('click', checkName); // check when the button is clicked
});

let checkName = () => {
  var a = $("#name").val().trim();
  var b = $("#verifyname").text().trim();  
  $('#one').text(a.toUpperCase() == b.toUpperCase() ? 'right' : 'wrong');
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.6.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<h4 id="verifyname">Foobar</h4>
<input type="text" id="name" />

<button type="button">Check</button>
<span id="one"></span>
```

Comment: Thanks a lot. i guess i better look at jquery in detail.

Comment: No problem, glad to help. If you want to learn more about jQuery the docs are here: https://api.jquery.com/